# Ошибка при развертывании: Не удалось запустить Tomcat

Tags: java-ee, netbeans, tomcat

Установил NetBeans 8.1 вместе с Томкат 8. Создаю новое веб-приложение, но при развертывании выдает ошибку

```
Не удалось запустить Tomcat.
C:\Users\malykh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1070: Ошибка при развертывании: Не удалось запустить Tomcat.
```

После исправлений из топика https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485487/error-starting-tomcat-from-netbeans-127-0-0-1-is-not-recognized-as-an-inter томкат запускается, но ошибка меняется на новую

```
Сервер Tomcat запущен.
Развертывание на месте на C:\Users\malykh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web
Выполняется развертывание...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fmalykh%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext2972887353435846638.xml&path=/WebApplication1
Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost:8084/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fmalykh%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext2972887353435846638.xml&path=/WebApplication1
C:\Users\malykh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1070: Модуль не развернут.
```

1069-1071 строки файла build-impl.xml выглядят следующим образом:

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>
```

Логи сервера:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.27
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2015 08:17:25 UTC
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.27.0
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.prognoz.ru
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.prognoz.ru|192.168.*|10.*|<local>
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.prognoz.ru
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\logging.properties
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\endorsed
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:\app\malykh\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;.
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.915 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.976 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.979 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.983 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Feb-2016 15:02:26.983 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 575 ms
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.27
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.009 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.308 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml has finished in 299 ms
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.308 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.373 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.375 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 67 ms
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.376 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.382 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Feb-2016 15:02:27.385 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 401 ms
```

Пробовал переустанавливать среду c сервером. Ставить отдельно Томкат по инструкции https://odba.ru/showthread.php?t=285 и подключать к НетБинс. Менять порты. Максимум менялся код ошибки с 503 на 400. Уже не знаю, что делать

Переставил все в C:\Web, теперь Tomcat вообще отказывается запускаться

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Web\Tomcat8"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Web\Tomcat8\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Web\Tomcat8\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
фев 24, 2016 4:39:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp
фев 24, 2016 4:39:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\server.xml]
фев 24, 2016 4:39:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp
фев 24, 2016 4:39:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [C:\Users\malykh\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\server.xml]
фев 24, 2016 4:39:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Comment: По поводу переноса на "C://.." - посмотрите конфигурацию Tomcat`а. Складывается впечатление, что вы просто взяли и скопировали весь дистрибутив из предыдущей  папки. Вас должны интересовать CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE, CATALINA_TMPDIR (сейчас они разбросаны, стоит настроить все на новую папку c:/Web)

Comment: @EvgenyLazarev Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу переноса на "C://.." - посмотрите конфигурацию Tomcat`а. Складывается впечатление, что вы просто взяли и скопировали весь дистрибутив из предыдущей папки. Вас должны интересовать `CATALINA_HOME`, `CATALINA_BASE`, `CATALINA_TMPDIR` (сейчас они разбросаны, стоит настроить все на новую папку c:/Web)

Answer (score 0):

Сергей, добрый день. Судя по логам запуска у вас очень много каталогов с пробелами в названиях. Java не всегда корректно их обрабатывает, как и каталоги с кирилицей в названии. Как вариант сделайте папку work на диске c:\ и установите туда Netbeans и TomCat, также в каталоги без пробелов. При создании нового проекта, также указывайте папку проекта без кирилицы и пробелов в названии.